# Syntax error in jinja 2 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jinja2

For running the IPython Notebook on a suse Linux server, I needed to install the `jinja2` library:

```
pip-3.2 install jinja2
```

Installation printed [a syntax error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6240497) but also said "installation successful".

On import, I get the following error:

```
In [1]: import jinja2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 639
    u'\xff\xff\xff\xff'.encode('iso-8859-15')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Bug in the jinja2 package? Any way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jinja2 only supports Python 3.3 and up, you are trying to install it for Python 3.2. Quoting from the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#experimental-python-3-support):

> Jinja 2.7 brings experimental support for Python >=3.3.

Python 3.3 added support for `u'..'` string literals to make it easier to write compatible code that runs both on Python 2 and 3, which Jinja2 makes use of.

You'll either have to upgrade to Python 3.3, or pick a different templating library or use an earlier version.

The requirement was upgraded to 3.3 in version 2.7 (see the [changelog](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/CHANGES)), so you could try installing 2.6:

```
pip install jinja2==2.6
```

Answer (score 6):

Install jinja 2.5, using:

```
easy_install jinja2==2.5
```

That solved the problem for me (happily).

Comment: Thanks, 2.6 didn't work for me (produced another error) but 2.5 did.