# Jinja2.5 Syntax error on import

Tags: python, syntax-error, raspbian, jinja2

I am using Python 3.2.3. And I installed Jinja2.5 by downloading from this page: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.5.5`

Then I used the setup.py to install it. This seemed worked like a charm. When I tested it by using this line:

```
from jinja2 import Template
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.5.5-py3.2.egg/jinja2/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.5.5-py3.2.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.5.5-py3.2.egg/jinja2/nodes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup, MethodType, FunctionType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.5.5-py3.2.egg/jinja2/utils.py", line 585, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py", line 70
    def __new__(cls, base=u'', encoding=None, errors='strict'):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is on my Raspberry pi with Raspbian installed. I don't know why this error occures, because the docs say Jinja2.5 and Python 3.2 are compatible.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing `python --version` if the reply does not say Python 3. something then your default python is python 2 and so does not support `u''` for unicode strings.

If this is the case you need to install `jinja2` by using `pip3 install jinja2` and run your scripts with `python3 scriptname.py`.

Other than that see: [Syntax error in jinja 2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252804/syntax-error-in-jinja-2-library?rq=1) basically python 3.2 is no longer supported so the choice is pick another library or upgrade python.

Comment: I used the following command to test this: sudo pip3.2 install jinja2. This said it was already installed. I also always on purposely type: python3.2 to make sure I have the right version

Comment: Have you tried the current version of jinja2 - as of today I make it 2.7.2.

Comment: As stated in the Jinja docs: "support for Python 3.2 was dropped in Jinja2 version 2.7"

Comment: looks like you are not the only one with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252804/syntax-error-in-jinja-2-library?rq=1 - the accepted answer there was either pick another library or upgrade to python3.3.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will have to pick another library then. Thanks for the help anyway!